# french chraracters in browsers

Tags: browser, internationalization, cross-browser

What is the solution to correctly display french characters in all browsers? now i get in some browsers this: (pr�sent�s)
Thanks.

Comment: What charset meta tag are you using in your webpages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to learn how to use [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Try UTF-8 encoding on all your pages and encoding all your strings to UTF-8.

Comment: Unicode is *one* solution, but not the only one. Besides, it's only part of the solution; if the browser doesn't know what encoding to use, it still doesn't help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a content type for the page, and specify what encoding you use for creating the page. Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Judging by what he says he's seeing, chances are he's using ISO-Latin-1 instead of UTF-8.  What's the official charset, ISO-9660-1?  Something like that.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 and 8859-15 is what ancient systems use in that region. [9660 is the ISO thing for CDs.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) for your page. In your editor, save to that encoding, and specify in the HTML `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=The_Chosen_Encoding" />
```

Suitable encodings for French include ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1) and UTF-8.

Alternatively, you may stick to plain ASCII and use [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the accentuated letters, such as:

- &eacute; for é
- &egrave; for è
- etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this in you html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

and if you're using php additionally this in your php-script

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: The php header() call won't help you much, especially when the user saves the page for later offline reading. <meta> is how it's supposed to be done indeed.